# jQuery add class to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, dynamic

I create elements inside a JSON parsing function. I'd like to add a class to some of them in case they contain a specific string. I tried to add an element at the end of the parsing function which would later be checked if it has loaded, but it's useless in case of long loading time since the parsing is an asynchronous process. How can I check if the parsing has been completed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON(data, function(dat) {
    $.each(dat, function (k, da) {
      $('div').append('<p>'+ da.string +'</p>');
    });
    $('div').append('<p id="loaded">loaded</p>'); 
  });

  var loaded = setInterval(function() { 
    if ($('#loaded').length) { 
      $('p:contains("blahblah")').addClass('blah');
      clearInterval(checkExist); 
    } 
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add your class when creating the element?

Comment: well, there is also a  content added from an outside function, therefor it's not known at the time of creation

Comment: You can try using `$.ajax` to get the data. It have `.done` and `.always` . I did some test on jsfiddle on firefox. `always` is called after `done` has completed execution. I was not able to find this documented anywhere so you may need to test and confirm or look into library. Link to fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/zjoy60mn/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in contains..please use this

```
$("p:contains(blahblah)").addClass('blah');
```